# jQuery toggle doesn't work for qtip until it shows once

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I'm asking for some help about the way to use a toggle with qtip2.

In my case, I use qtip to show form errors for each element. It works fine when I want it shows with the "mouseenter".
But I try some changes. I add an icon near to my form element and the qtip toggle with click on this icon.
My problem is the toggle doesn't work until the qtip shows once (with the mousenter event configure in the qtip). If I set the option "show" to "false" in the config, the qtip never show. And I don't want to user "ready" because I don't want qtip shows in page load.

(and sorry for the quality of my english, I hope your eyes don't bleed too much...)

Comment: what version of jQuery you are using ? see this --> http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: It would be better if post some code to see what is happening in there?